# IMCE module: list only image files

Tags: files

I have a Drupal 7 with the IMCE module installed.
It works good but it shows me every files in my media directory. 
I need to limit the listing to only image files, for example to only jpg, png and svg file.

Anybody know a way to do it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict by placing file extensions which you want to display in the permitted file extensions field. It will appear in the configuration of IMCE profiles. See below image for your reference.

[image]